# Evaluation Order with string and ints

Tags: java, string, operators

```
  String s1 = "six" + 3 + 3;
  String s2 = 3 + 3 + "six:";
  System.out.println(s1);
  System.out.print(s2);
```

Output :

```
  six33
  6six:
```

Why is 3+3 not added in the first one but is added in the second one?

Comment: Because the additions are performed left-to-right. `"six"+3` is `"six3"`. But `3 + 3` is `6`

Comment: `int` + `int` is an `int`. `int` + `String` is a `String`. `String s2 = String.valueOf(3) + 3 + "six";` **or** `String s2 = "" + 3 + 3 + "six";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the operation is important

In the first one the concatenation works like so :

```
String s1 = "six" + 3 + 3;
            "six3" + 3  // string plus int return string
            "six33"     // string plus int return string
```

In the second one :

```
String s2 = 3 + 3 + "six:";
            6 + "six"  // int plus int return int
            "6six"     // int plus string return string
```

---

For more details read documentation of [**Operators**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and [**15.7. Evaluation Order**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated
>   from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

Comment: Thanks. So in java, whenever I evaluate an output I always follow the order of catenation from left to right. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you can view pretty much any concatenation `a + b + c + d` as `(((a + b) + c) + d)`.

Answer (score 1):

In S1, the compiler reads (six) characters, then reads and reads. The numerical value of number 3 cannot be summed with text (six), as a character and added after x, then reads 3 and added after the first 3.

In s2 he reads 3 and then 3 can execute the process collected by the compiler and prints 6 directly and then reads (six) can not be collected will be printed after the number 6

Answer (score 0):

Order is important. In second case firstly it does arithmetic operation and string concatenation so it results in 6six